# Emacs powerline inconsistent colors behind arrows

Tags: themes, mode-line, powerline

I just setup powerline for the first time and there's this whitish transparent background overtop all of the arrows. Is there anyway to fix this?

[image]

Also, while we're at it, just a general question:

What does the 2.24 in the mode line mean?

Comment: Try to report at GitHub issue tracker for this project: https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues. As a note: all powerline implementations for Emacs seem to be buggy for me with respect to rendering. Never got pretty powerline working, so I still use default (cleaned up) mode line.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: 2.24 means average load of your CPU in percents, I believe. It's refreshed once pre minute or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is it possible you're running on a Mac? Then add this to your `init.el`:

```
(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)
```

See this Github issue for further context: https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/54

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is applicable to this specific case, but for powerline/spaceline users, even though `(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)` fixes the colors, it does this by applying the bad colors to all Emacs GUI, so you don't notice the effect anymore.

A better solution is to use `(setq powerline-image-apple-rgb t)` so the image generation uses the sRGB colors.

Answer (score 0):

What actually fixed it for me was using https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport, which works much better with OSX.